# Compass watcher in WebStorm fails to compile my .scss files

Tags: sass, webstorm, compass, file-watcher

I've been trying for some hours to make WebStorm's Compass watcher compile my .scss files, but it fails and I can't understand why.

I'm creating an empty test project with WebStorm and after that run
          `compass create`
and get an error from the watcher about screen.scss that it can't find 'compass'

```
error sass/screen.scss (Line 6: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.
```

I tried a couple of solutions which didn't work for me:

1. created a symlink from
   `C:\Ruby23\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\compass-1.0.3\bin\compass`
   to my sass folder;
2. added the compass directory as a resource in the project 
   `File->Settings->Directories`;
3. re-installed compass.

The config.rb settings are the default ones:

[image: config.rb settings]

These are my watcher's settings, I will provide other information if needed
[image: Compass SCSS watcher settings]

Comment: please can you provide a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. 
Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/mzgcezS.png) of the error message.
But, after some more research I don't think the problem stems from WebStorm at all. Tried compiling my files manually with compass and it still behaves the same.